# How to open the youtube link from a youtube video embed in a PyQt5 Widget in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Environment:

Python 3.7
PyQT5 5.15.2

I have a GUI with some links and Youtube videos embed inside a QWidget.

A GUI is a user interface. I've done mine for my software with Python PyQT5.
I want to show some video tutorials from YOutube inside my GUI.

So I incorporate the youtube iframe HTML code inside a Qwidget (vlayout & webview, see code below).

The GUI is loading fine, and the videos are playing well. But they are too small. So my users will click on the youtube link over the video:

[image]

When I click on this Youtube link when playing the video, it supposes to open a youtube video page from my browser. It is useful to watch it directly from youtube instead of from my GUI.
But the link doesn't work. it doesn't do anything. Something is wrong.

SO I tried to play with 'setOpenExternalLinks' & 'centralwid', but it doesn't work. The widget for my youtube doesn't have this attribute.

```
AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'setOpenExternalLinks'
```

Why?

Here is the code of some youtube videos and labels:

```
# Code for 1 Youtube video and its QtWidget
# ======================================================================================
self.centralwid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tab_run)
self.centralwid.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 410, 258))
self.centralwid.setObjectName("centralwid")
self.label_loading_browsers = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwid)
# ===================== HERE IS THE CODE FOR IFRAM YOUTUBE ============================
self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
self.webview = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
self.webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
self.webview.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(lambda request: request.accept())
baseUrl = "local"
htmlString = """
                <iframe width="350" height="212" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g8NVwN0_mks?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        """

self.webview.setHtml(htmlString, QUrl(baseUrl))
self.vlayout.addWidget(self.webview)
self.centralwid.setLayout(self.vlayout)
```

I search for all the properties and methods of my object qwidget.
I added these 2 lines but it didn't change anything:

```
self.webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
self.webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowRunningInsecureContent, True)
```

Here is MiniMum Reproductable COde (just copy paste in a py file and execute, you may need to resize window of gui to see the video)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings

# Subclass QMainWindow to customise your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")

        label = QLabel("This is a PyQt5 window!")

        # The `Qt` namespace has a lot of attributes to customise
        # widgets. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Set the central widget of the Window. Widget will expand
        # to take up all the space in the window by default.
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        # Code for 1 Youtube video and its QtWidget
        # ======================================================================================

        self.centralwid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwid.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 410, 258))
        self.centralwid.setObjectName("centralwid")
        self.label_loading_browsers = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwid)
        # ===================== HERE IS THE CODE FOR IFRAM YOUTUBE ============================
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.webview = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)        
        self.webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
        self.webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowRunningInsecureContent, True)
        self.webview.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(lambda request: request.accept())
        baseUrl = "local"
        htmlString = """
                        <iframe width="350" height="212" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g8NVwN0_mks?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                """

        self.webview.setHtml(htmlString, QUrl(baseUrl))
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.webview)
        self.centralwid.setLayout(self.vlayout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Did you try using `IPython.display.IFrame()` with PyQT5? Usually gets the job done in Jupyter Notebooks

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc for helping. I never heard about that method. I couldn't find any tuto for showing a youtube iframe on a PyQT5 gui with "IPython.display.IFrame()"

Comment: 1) Your question is not clear, 2) provide an MRE, 3) explain what it means to you that it does not work, 4) the link you provide indicates that the video no longer exists.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Let me edit the question.

Comment: I reformulated my question with more explanations. You can reproduce issue by copy pasting my code in any PyQT5 GUI. It will show the youtube frame. Play the video and try to click on the link (the title).

Comment: I already have a possible solution but my question is why do you use iframe?

Comment: I found a tutorial 6 months ago. I just pick up the first working solution to display youtube videos on my GUI.

Comment: Do you only want to show the video, don't you want to show the other pages of the video such as the chat or the other suggestion videos that by default appear on the official youtube page? Please use `@username`

Comment: I need the simplest way : SHow video, play it from GUI, and if user click, it open the youtube URL. Nothing else.

Comment: @GauthierButtez It is that my doubt is that you do not understand the dimension of the problem (or perhaps I am very exquisite). I have managed to redirect it after pressing the link that is in the upper part of the video but this redirects me to the official YouTube page where the complete elements are, such as: the chat below the video, the list of suggested videos on the side right, the search input on the right page, etc. Do you want that or do you want only that video to appear inside another iframe only?

Comment: Yes I want the official page with everything but I can't from my side. That means it is my environmental problem as I can't open it. I execute the MRC published above and when I click, nothing happen.

Comment: When I make a right click on the link, I see Open URL, save URL, etc... neither these menus doesn't work. I deactivated my antivirus. I run the script from windows command terminal as admin.... Nothing worked :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that according to the standard there are several types of actions when a link is clicked: Open the link on the same page, in another tab, window, etc. So in your case you have not implemented that logic (for example in Google Chrome I will have it in another tab). The solution is to override the createWindow method.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineSettings, QWebEngineView


popups = []


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.view)
        self.resize(640, 480)


class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def createWindow(self, _type):
        w = Widget()
        w.show()
        popups.append(w)
        return w.view.page()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=None)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        label = QLabel("This is a PyQt5 window!", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        self.page = WebEnginePage()
        self.webview.setPage(self.page)
        self.webview.settings().setAttribute(
            QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True
        )

        self.webview.load(
            QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/g8NVwN0_mks?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0")
        )

        lay = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addWidget(self.webview)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you but it will spoil my GUI. I would prefer to open it in a PyQt5 popup. Is that possible?

Comment: @GauthierButtez You realize that to avoid these inconveniences I prefer you to point out precisely what you want but you tell me: it doesn't matter, I just want the page to open, don't you think that's annoying?

Comment: Amazing! Sorry for being complicated. I tried my best to help you to understand my issue. Your solution can't open URL in browser, but it does the main job! Thanks!